# comparison of 2 dates in multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I have the following table that I would like to compare

I have to compare dates per employee and if the date range is less than 60 days it has to extract the employee.
example:

- the employee with number 4 has 3 records (4479,4192,1982)
- The combination of these 3 records (4479-4192, 4479-1982, 4192-1982) the dates must be compared and if one of them is less than 60 days, the employee must be extracted.

below the example table:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b44d4e

| id | idEmployee | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1228 | 2 | 2020-06-11 21:10:53 |
| 3382 | 2 | 2020-06-11 12:37:04 |
| 2223 | 2 | 2020-08-17 21:10:57 |
| 4479 | 4 | 2020-08-17 12:37:08 |
| 4192 | 4 | 2020-07-29 12:37:08 |
| 1982 | 4 | 2020-07-29 21:10:56 |
| 2627 | 8 | 2020-04-16 12:37:02 |
| 474 | 8 | 2020-04-16 21:10:49 |
| 1002 | 10 | 2020-05-29 21:10:52 |
| 3150 | 10 | 2020-05-29 12:37:04 |

pd: mysql database

Any help or suggestion how should I make the query?

Comment: thanks, now i check it

Comment: You have both "greater than 60 days" and "less than 60 days" in the question. Which is it really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an exists approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT idEmployee
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.idEmployee = t1.idEmployee AND
                    DATEDIFF(t2.date, t1.date) > 60);
```

In plain English, the above query says to return any employee record for which we can find another record of the same employee more than 60 days apart.  The distinct select removes duplicates.

Comment: Is it greater than 60 days or less than 60 days?

Comment: you are right friend, your query is correct. Thanks for the help

Comment: I was confused in the details of the question but it is less than 60 days, it is still the correct answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use exists

```
select * from table t1
where exists ( 
  select 1 from table t2
  where t1.idEmployee = t2.idEmployee
  and t2.Id <> t1.id 
  and abs(datediff(t2.date, t1.date)) < 60)
```

Comment: @Barmar This is also not clear to me (maybe the source of all the downvotes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-join

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.idEmployee
FROM employees AS a
JOIN employees AS b ON a.idEmployee = b.idEmployee AND DATEDIFF(a.date, b.date) > 60
```

But instead of comparing all with all, you really only need to compare the most extreme dates with each other. If they're less than 60 days apart, all the other dates must also be less.

```
SELECT idEmployee
FROM employees
GROUP BY idEmployee
HAVING DATEDIFF(MAX(a.date), MIN(a.date)) > 60
```

Comment: You are right, I only have to buy the extreme dates and know if it is less than 60 days, now I was making a producible example so as not to have my question negative

Comment: @Iteprevengo but you said you want the ones that are less than 60. so I don't think second query works .

Comment: @eshirvana The question is inconsistent. First it said "greater than 60" then later it said "less than 60".

Comment: I think that if I need to compare all the records, not only compare the minimum and maximum dates, this table will be filled when an employee tested positive for covid, then I need to compare the dates and make it less than 60 days to keep a count of reinfected

Comment: if it's okay what you say friend, I have already corrected the details of the question